# Firestore: cannot securely query data with a WHERE clause that uses both currentUser.uid and FieldPath.documentId()

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

*firestore.rules*

```
match /databases/{database} {
    match /documents/board/{boardId}/{document=**} {
        allow read: if (resource.data.creatorId == request.auth.uid);
```

*query 1 (works)*

```
this.db
        .collection("board")
        .where("creatorId", "==", app.auth().currentUser.uid).onSnapshot(...)
```

*query 2 (doesnt work, returns `FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions`)*

```
this.db
        .collection("board")
        .where("creatorId", "==", app.auth().currentUser.uid)
        .where(app.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), "in", boardIds).onSnapshot(...)
```

This doesn't make any sense to me. Query 2 is a *subset* of Query 1 and yet, unlike Query 1, violates the security rules.

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 2):

Your security rules prevent reading a document if the creatorId of it is not the user making the query.

**Query 1** works because the filter follows the rule and will not read documents whose creator is not the current user.

Then, **Query 2** has that second clause which means:
"I want the documents whose DocID is one of the boardIds array".

The problem might be that the documentID is considered a field of a document.

If one were to apply the second clause alone it will probably crash because userA may try to access a userB document to check if the docID is in the array, which is not allowed.

So, even-though the **RESULT** of the second query would be a subset of query 1, this doesn't mean (or seems to mean) the QUERY itself is allowed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Nibrass.

I'm still not totally grasping this though. I tried storing `id` as an explicit field of each board document, so that query 2 becomes:

this.db
        .collection("board")
        .where("creatorId", "==", app.auth().currentUser.uid)
        .where("id", "in", boardIds).onSnapshot(...)

and it suddenly works! I can only understand this in terms of FieldPath.documentId() having some special properties. Or possibly I've stumbled upon a bug.

Comment: I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61756336/11668444) explaining the fieldPath.documentID() bit further, as it doesn't really return an ID but a string field path, which might be the issue here.